# Shell on ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want to test some C-code on Nexus 7 under Ubuntu touch. Before installing Ubuntu touch on the tablet, I have some questions :

Is it possible to compile (gcc ?) and run the code directly in the tablet in the same way as on a laptop ?

Is there a shell where the command-line works as on laptop or desktop computer, on Ubuntu Touch ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is Yes (for both questions), but before testing your code on the Nexus 7 (2013), you'll need to run Utopic (14.10) on your laptop/desktop to get access to the latest development tools.

1. Follow the [installation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) steps (using the development channel to get a 14.10 image).
2. Install the required packages to manage your device:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash phablet-tools
   ```
3. Install the SDK

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
   ```
4. Connect your device and enable read-write mode (using the SDK):

   [image]
5. Push a sample code to your device ([hello.c](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_9.html)):

   ```
   $ adb push hello.c /home/phablet
   1 KB/s (82 bytes in 0.041s)
   ```
6. Start a phablet shell connection, install `gcc` and `libc6-dev` (root password is **phablet**) and compile your code on the target:

   ```
   sylvain@sylvain-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ phablet-shell 
   start: Job is already running: ssh
   /home/sylvain/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
   Original contents retained as /home/sylvain/.ssh/known_hosts.old
   4 KB/s (200 bytes in 0.040s)
   Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:2222' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
   Welcome to Ubuntu Utopic Unicorn (development branch) (GNU/Linux 3.4.0-3-flo armv7l)

    * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
   Last login: Wed Jul  9 21:29:20 2014 from localhost.localdomain
   phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ sudo apt-get update
   [sudo] password for phablet: 

   [...]

   phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc libc6-dev

   [...]

   phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ gcc -Wall hello.c -o hello
   phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ ls
   Documents  Downloads  hello  hello.c  Music  Pictures  Videos
   phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ ./hello
   Hello, world!
   phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$
   ```