# Start phablet-shell connection to Ubuntu Phone

Tags: command-line, ssh, ubuntu-touch, phone

I see in a few places [1,2,3] that I can securely connect from my Ubuntu desktop to my Ubuntu phone using the command `phablet-shell` from the `phablet-tools` package. Yet, from a terminal on my desktop, `phablet-shell` returns `phablet-shell: command not found`

```
desktop~$ adb devices
  1111aaaa2222bbbb    device
desktop~$ phablet-shell
  phablet-shell: command not found
desktop~$ apt-cache policy phablet-tools
  Installed: 1.0+14.04.20140416-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.0+14.04.20140416-0ubuntu1
desktop~$ whereis phablet-shell
  phablet-shell:
```

How can I start a secure shell connection between my desktop and phone? Can I do it using `universe` packages?

[1] [Shell on ubuntu touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493656/shell-on-ubuntu-touch)

[2] [Ubuntu touch - remote access to device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538129/ubuntu-touch-remote-access-to-device/538163#538163)

[3] https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/TouchTesting/BugReporting

Answer (score 1):

What is the output of `dpkg -L phablet-tools`? it should show you all the files installed by that package, and on my machine I can definitely see `/usr/bin/phablet-shell` among them.

I had a few issues to be able to connect afterwards, here's what I did:

- Enable the developer mode on the phone (phablet-shell won't complain that it cannot connect, so it was a bit confusing at first)
- simply running phablet-shell again didn't work either, so I tried as superuser: `sudo phablet-shell`
- This worked, and the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file has been updated, but is now owned by root, restore the correct permissions: `sudo chown youruser:youruser .ssh/known_hosts`
- `phablet-shell` now works!

And remember to unlock your device when you want to connect (just like when you want to transfer data), otherwise you'll get `error: closed` and exit code `255`

Comment: It seems that there's no phablet-shell on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Indeed I'm using 14.10

Comment: I had the same issue and I needed to generate ssh public key before berdario's solution works.
On your home directory : > ssh-keygen -t dsa After this and doing berdario's commands, I've got the right command line on my Ubuntu touch.

Comment: There is a [phablet-tools PPA](https://launchpad.net/~phablet-team/+archive/ubuntu/tools) for newer versions of the package.